# Meteor setInterval on server side

Tags: meteor

What have I do, to use Meteor.setInterval on server side?
When I use it, it's work, but I get:

```
Exception in setInterval callback: Error: Method not found [404] 
I20150429-15:47:50.897(2)?  at [object Object]._.extend.apply (packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:1502:1) 
I20150429-15:47:50.897(2)?    at [object Object]._.extend.call 
(packages/ddp/livedata_server.js:1472:1) 
I20150429-15:47:50.897(2)?   
 at app/server/cronJob.js:35:43 
I20150429-15:47:50.897(2)?    
 at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:56:1)
 I20150429-15:47:50.897(2)?   at packages/meteor/timers.js:6:1 
I20150429-15:47:50.898(2)? at runWithEnvironment
(packages/meteor/dynamics_nodejs.js:108:1)
```

I get this error even then I try this:

```
Meteor.setInterval(function(){
console.log("test");
});
```

Why it happens?

Comment: Post the entire page of code where you put setInterval, and where this page is in the directory structure.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify a delay for the interval, e.g., 5 seconds:

```
Meteor.setInterval(function(){
  console.log("test");
}, 5000);
```

It's hard to know what the behavior will be without a specified time interval.

Comment: Sorry, i tried with interval. My code looks like your and i have this error.

Comment: then you are not showing us relevant pieces. This code works. Just create a new project and paste nothing but this code into the server section of the code. It will run happily and print `test` on the console every five seconds.